# Top xx % this week/month/year percentage meaning and why it didn't write the rank (than percentage)?

Tags: discussion, reputation

What is the meaning of the **percentage** of top xx% this week/month/year? I know if I click the  `top xx% this week/month/year`, I will be directed to the user reputation leagues.

Why it didn't write the rank of the week/month/year than percentage? I think it is better to write the rank than the percentage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would rather be the top 3% this month on a site than be the ranked 379 user, they can have the same meaning.

For a site like Ask Ubuntu you would not feel so bad for it, take the same idea to a site like Stack Overflow and you can still be top 1% while ranking between 2 and 10 zillion...

It's just an opinion, not a fact.

Maybe a userscript can take care of that?